# Change remote URL during cloning

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-clone

Is there a way to change/replace repo URL during cloning?

I have main and mirror Bitbucket servers and my goal is to use local mirror as much as possible without making users to remember the mirror URL (which is slightly different from main on with both host name and a path). I want it to be completely transparent for developers.

I have a control over global config file.

Unfortunately I can't use DNS to do the job.

Comment: Do you want to change URL in case they clone the mirror? Or do a hot swap in case main repo is down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are hoping to set up a single remote reference for your repo, where one remote URL is used if it is available but a different remote URL is used if the first is not available (perhaps you are concerned about the network connection to the first remote failing).

I do not know of a way to do this, and I would not expect there to be a way to do this. By trying to treat two remotes as a single remote you might end up in a situation where the two remotes disagree and when cloning/pulling you get mixed results.

I would suggest setting up two separate remote references in your config file - one for each remote URL. Call the first something like `origin` and the second something like `origin-backup`. Then experiment with workflows where you (or your team developers) pick which remote to pull from.

Unfortunately you and your team will have to manually handle any differences between the two remotes. Perhaps there is a way to do what you are trying to do, but I don't think it will be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the URL *during* cloning.  You feed Git a URL and it clones from the URL; that connection is open; there's nothing to change.  Once the clone finishes—well, technically, just before the clone starts, but it looks the same from the outside—Git writes the URL *to* the clone's `.git/config` and stops, and now, *after* the clone, you can change the stored URL all you want, at any time.

To do this, at whatever time you like, run `git remote set-url name-of-remote new-url` while in the clone.  Git will store the new URL under that remote-name (probably you just want `origin` here).  The next time you use that remote-name, Git will translate it to the stored URL.  It's technically possible to run this command *while* `git clone` is still running, but it's not a good idea as `git clone` is going to write more stuff to `.git/config` and the two writes to `.git/config` could collide with each other (in which case one of them will fail, and it's not predictable which one).

Comment: I see. So, the only solution is to modify git-clone to replace the URL there. Is it correct?

Comment: The original clone will use main server instead of mirror. My intention is to use mirror server only.

Comment: So, after you do the clone, update the URL. I don't see the problem. Hand the first URL to `git clone` and the second URL to `(cd new-clone; git remote set-url origin)`. To do this as a single shell command, use `&&`, as in `git clone url1 && (cd new-clone && git remote set-url origin url2)`. When the command finishes you have a clone with the desired URL #2.

Comment: My goal is NOT to use a main server. With your solution the initial clone is done off the main one.

Comment: With my process, the initial clone is from *any URL*. If you wish to use the mirror server, then use it. Subsequent operations are from *any URL*. If you wish to continue to use the mirror server, do so; if not, choose some other URL. Note that you can put this all in a script that provides the two URLs, if some users have trouble remembering both.